# Enable read permission to parent directory in Subversion

Tags: apache, svn, permissions

I'm having trouble setting up my Subversion.
I'm currently able to access repository directories within the parent directory. i.e http://server.com/svn/project but I receive a Forbidden error if I try to access the parent directory directly http://server.com/svn/

Ideally, I would like to be able to see all my repositories from a single url so I'm trying to get this configured properly.

I have looked at /etc/apache2/conf.d/subversion.conf and I have set

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My SVN"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/conf/user_authentication.conf
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/conf/svn_authorization.conf
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
         Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

In /etc/apache2/conf/svn_authorization.conf  I have configured

```
[/]
* = r

[project:/]
user1 = rw
```

etc..

I'm not quite sure why I am getting forbidden on parent since I believe I have read enabled for all users. I have even tried removing the * = r and putting myUsername = r but still forbidden.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion won't show you the parent path directly. So "out of the box" you can't get the list of repositories this way. When using the web browser to access your repository, you should use viewvc, because that has many advantages to directly pointing the browser at the repository location (i.e. you can browse the history that way). If you're using a bundled SVN installation such as CollabNet, viewvc is automatically configured for your server, too.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Keeps me from banging my head much longer on something I can't do. I'll check viewvc out